# Option of create multiple accounts for each identity provider not working as expected in Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

*As you can see in the image below, I enabled the second option (Create multiple accounts for each identity provider)*

[image]

*Now this email `m6454611@gmail.com` is already in Firebase Authentication and I already logged in using Google provider.*

*I want to create a new account with the same email in the above but with the email provider but it tells me email account registration unsuccessful. It will work without any problems if I delete the email that signed in via Google provider.*

[image]

*I expected it will create the same email without any problems because it is a different provider*

*Did I misunderstand anything?*

Comment: Still waiting for any reply from the Firebase team such as Frank van Puffelen, Alex Mamo, Doug Stevenson, Renaud Tarnec, and etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linking multiple providers to the same account, you don't use the create user method there is a link method for it:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

```
import { getAuth, linkWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
linkWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential)
  .then((usercred) => {
    const user = usercred.user;
    console.log("Account linking success", user);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Account linking error", error);
  });
```

Basically, the behavior is that the account is already created, and already logged on, and then you can link their existing account with a new provider.

Comment: There is a problem with Firebase UI as you can see in the image above, Why is that happening?

Comment: Have you tried creating the account using another provider? not custom? Also, you don't need to be logged in to create a new account.

Comment: What do you mean when you say not custom?

Comment: I mean not email - pass, another provider, like FB, github, Microsoft, not native.

Comment: Let's suppose there are no users yet in Firebase Authentication, I'll create a new account using the email provider button (Custom as you said), The email was m6454611@gmail.com, When press on the saves button will add the account to Firebase without any problems, But if m6454611@gmail.com already existed in the Firebase I'll get this message: Email account registration unsuccessful.

Comment: I tried to sign in using different providers without any problems even if was the same email

Comment: So that would be the base case, accordingly to the documentation you can sigup with multiple providers but it seems that google creates for you that email unique entity, so different providers doesn't include native ones.